# What is Cousin Itt in The Addams Family?

Tags: addams-family

Is Itt human under all that hair, or is the hair itself a living kind of entity similar to Thing?

Comment: I always thought he was a distant relative of [Chi Eekway Papanoida](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chi_Eekway_Papanoida).

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're asking this question you're doing itt wrong.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Gomez and Cousin Itt discussed this very point in the season 2 episode [*Morticia's Romance, Part I*](https://addamsfamily.fandom.com/wiki/Morticia%27s_Romance:_Part_1)

> **Gomez:** *Underneath all that hair, you really are... What are you underneath all that hair?*
>
> **Itt:** [Makes noises]
>
> **Gomez:** ***Roots?** Makes sense.*

The assumption (from the season 2 episode [*Cousin Itt's Problem*](https://addamsfamily.fandom.com/wiki/Cousin_Itt%27s_Problem)) is that **without his hair, he'll be without form.**

> **Gomez:** *Cousin Itt, you're losing your hair.*
>
> **Morticia:** *He's right.*
>
> **Gomez:** *Without his hair, what is he?*
>
> **Morticia:** *Nothing. Absolutely nothing.*

Although they may have meant this figuratively rather than literally.

Comment: I definitely took both lines as intentionally avoiding answering the question (for humor, since you're naturally going to wonder).

Comment: @RichardRast - Aye. It's definitely a "don't ask!" trope.

Comment: Cousin Itt is like Popeye: "I yam what I yam an' dat's all what I yam". Except Cousin Itt is hair rather than a root vegetable.

Comment: He also had a (human) wife in the second Raul Julia Addam's Family movie, whatever that might mean...